# java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed while socket is still open

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception

So I'm trying to receive a message from my server when there comes a notification from Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). My code is the following:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
 //This class is executed by the BradcastReceiver when the devices
 //gets a message from GCM
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType();

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.i("INTENTSERVICE", extras.toString());
                sendNotification(extras);
            }
            Log.e("WAKELOCK","Wakelock will end");
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(final Bundle extras){
                Socket socket = null;
                FileOutputStream fileStream;
                MessageSet ms = null;
                try {

                    socket = new Socket(getString(R.string.server_address), 37133);
                    Tools.sendDataToServer(getApplicationContext(), 
                        socket, 
                        MessageTypes.PULLMESSAGE, 
                        extras.getString("content")); //sending does perfectly work

                    //Receive contents of Message
                    DataInputStream dis = 
                        new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // but now is doesn't 
                                                  //want to do more and the exception is thrown
                    byte type = dis.readByte();
                    /* doing things */ 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    //Tools.close(socket);
                }

                /* post notification */
    }
}
```

I can create the Socket and send Data to the server, wich is also received, but when I want to receive data on the phone afterwards, it gives an `java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed` Exception. But at the same time, the server is still sending data and the socket on the phone is also still open ([according to debugger [PIC]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhlEV.png)).

But why does this Error occur?

---

The requested code of `Tools.sendDataToServer`

```
public static void sendDataToServer(Context context, Socket socket, int messageType, String content){
        try {
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.SharedPrefs),0);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            out.write(messageType);
            byte[] msgBytes = (prefs.getString("userID","") + "|;" + prefs.getString("userSession","") + "|;" + content).getBytes("UTF-8");
            Tools.writeDataLengthToStream(out, msgBytes.length);
            out.write(msgBytes,0,msgBytes.length);
            out.flush();
            //out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When `out.close()` is commented out, it is working. Thats a problem I already had, but I still don't have a clue why it is like this.

Comment: what does the Tools.sendDataToServer do? Can you post that code?

Comment: @eldjon : thats the code, it works without the out.close() line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Socket* is closed. You closed it, in this application. The peer may still be trying to send data but it will get a 'connection reset' exception.

Comment: yeah, it was the problem, that after closing the outputStream, the socket will be closed, too. But I still don't know why, as the documentation doesn't really says anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

At least you have to close the Socket connection instance inside finally. Test if it is null, if you don't do that a reference may persist in memory. And also make sure that it is not executing in the main thread. After that if the same error persist, try to reinstall the application to clean up the memory cache.

And also avoid close the Socket instance inside the Tool Class.

Comment: Testing for null doesn't prevent instances from persisting in memory.

Comment: The Tools.close() is just a "shortcut" for `if ! Null then close` . Is this not a good practice?